# Simple Magento Description Addon

Tags: magento

I would like to receive some guidance or tips on how to create the following simple magento addon. I want to add a new tab when editing a product in the back-end, which for every product the admin can enter a few more details on a textarea which I will later on display on the product in the front-end on a separate tab.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom attribute to add a new field in all the products .

You can refer to this link:-

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields